# Getting JSON object response using Retrofit library

Tags: java, android, json, object, retrofit2

I need to get more than 300 values from json objects, but I used bean I have to declare 300 getters and setters?

Thank you

> ```
>  My Json:
>
>         "ME_1":"09:19",
>         "MS_1":"12:49",
>         "TE_1":"14:01",
>         "TS_1":"17:46",
>         "Total_1":7.25,
>         "ME_2":"SABADO",
>         "MS_2":"SABADO",
>         "TE_2":"SABADO",
>         "TS_2":"SABADO",
>         "EE_2":"SABADO",
>         "ES_2":"SABADO",
>         "E4_2":"SABADO",
>         "S4_2":"SABADO",
>         "E5_2":"SABADO",
>         "S5_2":"SABADO",
>         "Total_2":0,
>         "ME_3":"DOMINGO",
>         "MS_3":"DOMINGO",
>         "TE_3":"DOMINGO",
>         "TS_3":"DOMINGO",
>         "EE_3":"DOMINGO",
>         "ES_3":"DOMINGO",
>         "E4_3":"DOMINGO",
>         "S4_3":"DOMINGO",
>         "E5_3":"DOMINGO",
>         "S5_3":"DOMINGO",
>         "Total_3":0,
>         "ME_4":"09:20",
>         "MS_4":"12:00",
>         "TE_4":"13:59",
>         "TS_4":"18:43",
>         "Total_4":7.4,
>         "ME_5":"09:31",
>         "MS_5":"11:50",
>         "TE_5":"13:36",
>         "TS_5":"19:13",
>         "Total_5":7.933333333333334,
>         "ME_6":"09:31",
>         "MS_6":"12:42",
>         "TE_6":"13:41",
>         "TS_6":"18:04",
>         "Total_6":7.566666666666666,
>         "ME_7":"09:16",
>         "MS_7":"12:49",
>         "TE_7":"13:33",
>         "TS_7":"19:21",
>         "Total_7":9.35,
>         "ME_8":"09:32",
>         "MS_8":"12:45",
>         "TE_8":"14:36",
>         "TS_8":"18:43",
>         "Total_8":7.333333333333333,
>         "ME_9":"FERIADO",
>         "MS_9":"FERIADO",
>         "TE_9":"FERIADO",
>         "TS_9":"FERIADO",
>         "EE_9":"FERIADO",
>         "ES_9":"FERIADO",
>         "E4_9":"FERIADO",
>         "S4_9":"FERIADO",
>         "E5_9":"FERIADO",
>         "S5_9":"FERIADO",
>         "Total_9":0,
>         "ME_10":"DOMINGO",
>         "MS_10":"DOMINGO",
>         "TE_10":"DOMINGO",
>         "TS_10":"DOMINGO",
>         "EE_10":"DOMINGO",
>         "ES_10":"DOMINGO",
>         "E4_10":"DOMINGO",
>         "S4_10":"DOMINGO",
>         "E5_10":"DOMINGO",
>         "S5_10":"DOMINGO",
>         "Total_10":0,
>         "ME_11":"09:31",
>         "MS_11":"12:40",
>         "TE_11":"13:41",
>         "TS_11":"18:38",
>         "Total_11":8.1,
>         "ME_12":"09:31",
>         "MS_12":"12:00",
>         "TE_12":"13:40",
>         "TS_12":"19:44",
>         "Total_12":8.55,
>         "ME_13":"09:22",
>         "MS_13":"12:49",
>         "TE_13":"13:48",
>         "TS_13":"18:28",
>         "Total_13":8.116666666666667,
>         "ME_14":"09:22",
>         "MS_14":"11:59",
>         "TE_14":"13:39",
>         "TS_14":"19:17",
>         "Total_14":8.25,
>         "ME_15":"09:19",
>         "MS_15":"12:13",
>         "TE_15":"13:31",
>         "TS_15":"17:43",
>         "Total_15":7.1,
>         "ME_16":"SABADO",
>         "MS_16":"SABADO",
>         "TE_16":"SABADO",
>         "TS_16":"SABADO",
>         "EE_16":"SABADO",
>         "ES_16":"SABADO",
>         "E4_16":"SABADO",
>         "S4_16":"SABADO",
>         "E5_16":"SABADO",
>         "S5_16":"SABADO",
>         "Total_16":0,
>         "ME_17":"DOMINGO",
>         "MS_17":"DOMINGO",
>         "TE_17":"DOMINGO",
>         "TS_17":"DOMINGO",
>         "EE_17":"DOMINGO",
>         "ES_17":"DOMINGO",
>         "E4_17":"DOMINGO",
>         "S4_17":"DOMINGO",
>         "E5_17":"DOMINGO",
>         "S5_17":"DOMINGO",
>         "Total_17":0,
>         "ME_18":"09:26",
>         "MS_18":"12:54",
>         "TE_18":"13:52",
>         "TS_18":"19:18",
>         "Total_18":8.9,
>         "ME_19":"09:20",
>         "MS_19":"12:30",
>         "TE_19":"12:30",
>         "TS_19":"13:02",
>         "EE_19":"19:17",
>         "Total_19":3.6999999999999997,
>         "Obs_19":"-> Erro no Ponto! 2o. Per\u00EDodo - S\u00F3 existe o hor\u00E1rio da entrada.",
>         "ME_20":"09:14",
>         "MS_20":"12:42",
>         "TE_20":"13:42",
>         "TS_20":"19:23",
>         "Total_20":9.15,
>         "ME_21":"09:16",
>         "MS_21":"12:44",
>         "TE_21":"13:29",
>         "TS_21":"20:04",
>         "Total_21":10.05,
>         "ME_22":"09:27",
>         "MS_22":"12:34",
>         "TE_22":"13:41",
>         "TS_22":"18:38",
>         "Total_22":8.066666666666666,
>         "ME_23":"SABADO",
>         "MS_23":"SABADO",
>         "TE_23":"SABADO",
>         "TS_23":"SABADO",
>         "EE_23":"SABADO",
>         "ES_23":"SABADO",
>         "E4_23":"SABADO",
>         "S4_23":"SABADO",
>         "E5_23":"SABADO",
>         "S5_23":"SABADO",
>         "Total_23":0,
>         "ME_24":"DOMINGO",
>         "MS_24":"DOMINGO",
>         "TE_24":"DOMINGO",
>         "TS_24":"DOMINGO",
>         "EE_24":"DOMINGO",
>         "ES_24":"DOMINGO",
>         "E4_24":"DOMINGO",
>         "S4_24":"DOMINGO",
>         "E5_24":"DOMINGO",
>         "S5_24":"DOMINGO",
>         "Total_24":0,
>         "ME_25":"09:18",
>         "MS_25":"12:30",
>         "TE_25":"13:28",
>         "TS_25":"19:07",
>         "Total_25":8.850000000000001,
>         "Total_26":0,
>         "ME_27":"09:11",
>         "MS_27":"12:53",
>         "TE_27":"13:35",
>         "TS_27":"19:47",
>         "Total_27":9.9,
>         "ME_28":"09:17",
>         "MS_28":"13:01",
>         "TE_28":"13:44",
>         "TS_28":"20:47",
>         "Total_28":10.783333333333333,
>         "Obs_28":"-> Aten\u00E7\u00E3o, o colaborador trabalhou 7 ou mais horas e n\u00E3o houve intervalo de descanso preenchido.",
>         "ME_29":"09:29",
>         "MS_29":"12:42",
>         "TE_29":"13:40",
>         "TS_29":"18:46",
>         "Total_29":8.316666666666666,
>         "ME_30":"SABADO",
>         "MS_30":"SABADO",
>         "TE_30":"SABADO",
>         "TS_30":"SABADO",
>         "EE_30":"SABADO",
>         "ES_30":"SABADO",
>         "E4_30":"SABADO",
>         "S4_30":"SABADO",
>         "E5_30":"SABADO",
>         "S5_30":"SABADO",
>         "Total_30":0,
>         "ME_31":"DOMINGO",
>         "MS_31":"DOMINGO",
>         "TE_31":"DOMINGO",
>         "TS_31":"DOMINGO",
>         "EE_31":"DOMINGO",
>         "ES_31":"DOMINGO",
>         "E4_31":"DOMINGO",
>         "S4_31":"DOMINGO",
>         "E5_31":"DOMINGO",
>         "S5_31":"DOMINGO",
>         "Total_31":0,
>         "TotalHrTrab":164.66666666666666,
>         "Historico":
>         ["1a. Quinzena - Controle de Frequ\u00EAncia importado do Controle de Ponto por Ayla Batista em 20\/07\/2016 16:40:26","Controle
> ```
>
> de Frequ\u00EAncia Mensal gerado automaticamente pelo sistema em
>   07/08/2016 22:00:51"
>               ]
>           }

Comment: If you have an object with 300 fields, your design needs a rework

Comment: post you JSON here ...\

Comment: So u r problem is to create 300 json object ?

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrofit-android-tutorial-to-get-json-from-server/

Comment: For 300 json objects you have to create 300 getters and setters, there r no other way.

Comment: You should rectify your json response. Remove unnecessary data from response, also create a Bean (Model) class using jsonschema2pojo.org, just paste your json response in this and it will generate a Bean class for you... Hope it will help you

Comment: I use json's Lotus Notes domino. But of 300 fields half comes null but not always

Comment: i edit my answer with my json look that

Comment: use this to generate getter and setter for your JSON http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: @MaharithAdityaSS, the question is _I have to declare 300 getters and setters?_  not how to generate getters and setters?. If bean for the JSON response already created you don't need to use that website,in Android Studio just hit `Alt + Insert` and select `Generate getters and setters` will generate getters and setters.

Comment: My problem is if this is not something good, do Declare 300 getters and setters disrupt my application?

Comment: No, it won't disrupt anything. Just gets you closer to the multidex limit, which is not an issue. Why can't you manually parse out the data you actually need?